# How can I disable automatic send / receive for Outlook 2010 for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

There are lots of answers to disable automatic send / receive for Outlook for Windows, but not for Mac.

Does anyone know how to do this for Outlook 2010 for Mac?

The options offer no obvious capability, I've disabled all my 'Schedules' and defined it to 'Send All' and 'Send & Receive All' manually... but nothing stops emails from going in and out of my inbox at their will!

You can see my screenshot... I've tried this both enabled and disabled.

Thanks!
Adam

[image: Screenshot of my Schedules in Outlook 2010 for Mac]

Comment: What variety of email is it... pop or imap?

Comment: It's Microsoft Exchange - IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try...

In Outlook, go to *Preferences* >> *Accounts* >> Click the *Advanced* button at the bottom right.  Try unchecking the "Sync all IMAP folders"

I'm actually not familiar with the exchange settings, but this may point you in the right direction.

[image: Advanced Account Preferences]

Comment: Thanks Josh! But unfortunately, for Microsoft Exchange accounts, there is no such option. All you can adjust is security and login details. Ugh.